# Negative assertions in Cypress

Tags: cypress

In Cypress, if I have a button that triggers an asynchronous operation (like `fetch`), and I want to verify that clicking this button does *not* eventually trigger an error, is this enough?

```js
cy.findByTestId('the-button').click();
cy.findByTestId('error-msg').should('not.exist');
```

I suspect not. I think I need to use `cy.wait`, typically with a route, like this:

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '/endpoint').as('endpoint');
cy.findByTestId('the-button').click();
cy.wait('@endpoint');
cy.findByTestId('error-msg').should('not.exist');
```

But is that guaranteed to work? What if the endpoint responds, the `should('not.exist')` test passes, and then subsequently - because the page took some time to update in reply to the endpoint's response - an error occurs?

Are there some best practices to follow here?

A follow-up question: Would it be fair to say that there's a deep asymmetry between positive and negative assertions? If I understand correctly, Cypress retries assertions until they pass. So, effectively, a `should` assertion checks that the assertion is true at **some** future point in time. But with negative assertions what we often want to check is that the assertion is true at **every** future point in time. This makes me think that negative assertions are liable to be misleading.

Comment: As you say, that does **not** express _"does not eventually trigger an error"_ - Cypress will wait for a condition that's initially false to become true, but cannot wait until a condition that's true is... still true (how long for, even? If you could say "hasn't appeared within 2 seconds" what if it took 2.1 - and your tests _always_ take 2s longer).

Comment: It would be unusual for `the-button` to *only* cause an error message (when POST failed). If nothing happens when POST succeeds, the app is poorly designed.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts wait as long as needed to satisfy the assertion. If the element is present initially, `.should('not.exist')` will wait for it to go away.

So if the app permits, force the error to occur, then take the action that makes it go away, and then assert that it does not exist.

```js
// force the error
cy.intercept({
  method: 'POST', 
  url: '/endpoint',
  forceNetworkError: true,
  times: 1                 // only for first click
})
cy.findByTestId('the-button').click()
cy.findByTestId('error-msg').should('exist')

cy.intercept('POST', '/endpoint', {id:1})   // mock the API for fast response
cy.findByTestId('the-button').click()
cy.findByTestId('error-msg').should('not.exist')
```

Similar to testing a loading indicator.

---

For waiting with `cy.wait('@endpoint')`, remember that Javascript is **single-threaded** so the action caused by `cy.get('the-button').click()` should complete before `cy.wait('@endpoint')` executes.

If in doubt burn-test -

[Burning Tests with cypress-grep](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/burning-tests/)

```js
npx cypress run --spec my-spec.js --env grep="burn=10"
```